# Querying a running-percentage over a date range from MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to graph the % of users over time that have their Twitter account connected. The number of users changes constantly, and so does the % of them that connect their Twitter account.

The table has a user account specific `createDateTime` column as well as a `tw_connectDateTime` column.

Let's say I'm interested in the trend of % connected over the last 7 days. Is there a way I can have MSSQL calculate the percentage for every day in the specified range, or do I need to do it myself using multiple queries?

Doing it in app logic would look something like (pseudocode):

```
for day in days:
    query:
        select 
            count(userId) as totalUsers
            ,c.connected
            ,cast(c.connected as float)/count(userId) as percentage
        from 
            Users
            outer apply ( 
                select 
                    count(userId) as connected 
                from 
                    Users
                where 
                    tw_connectDateTime <= $day
            ) as c 
        where
            createDateTime <= $day
        group by
            c.connected
```

What I'm unsure of is how, if it's possible, to expand this to run for each day, so that the results include the date as a column and the same values that I would get from running the above query for each date in the range.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can use your query joined with days, like this:

```
 with cte_days as (
     select @DateStart as day
     union all
     select dateadd(dd, 1, c.[day]) as [day]
     from cte_days as c
     where c.[day] < @DateEnd
 )
 select
     d.[day],
     count(u.userId) as totalUsers,
     c.connected,
     cast(c.connected as float)/count(u.userId) as percentage
 from cte_days as d
     inner join Users as u on u.createDateTime <= d.[day]
     outer apply ( 
         select 
             count(T.userId) as connected 
         from Users as T
         where T.tw_connectDateTime <= d.[day]
    ) as c 
 group by d.[day], c.connected
```

Comment: Tried running this as-is and got: "Invalid object name: 'cte_days'." Swapped the order of cte_days and cte_numbers and got "Invalid object name: 'cte_numbers'." Additionally, I'll need to be able to calculate over an arbitrary set of days, not just the most recent (getDate()-N).

Comment: @AdamTuttle updated query. Where do you want to get your arbitrary set of days? If this in temp table, you can just remove all cte_.. and join on this temporary table (or table variable)

Comment: This is to be graphed in a dashboard, and the dashboard allows selection of a date range for all of the data to be visualized, this graph included.

Comment: @AdamTuttle so it's `@DateStart` and `@DateEnd` basically?

Comment: It won't be a stored proc, but yeah, you can think of it that way.

Comment: With DateStart = '2013-08-01' and DateEnd = '2013-09-24' I get the following error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "day" of recursive query "cte_days".

Comment: Write datestart like cast('2013-08-01' as datetime)